# Homogeneous Structures for Isotropic, Coisotropic, and Symplectic Subspaces?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, symplectic-linear-algebra

A symplectic vector space $\left (\mathbb{R}^{2n}, \omega\right )$ can be thought of as having 4 fundamental types of subspaces: Lagrangian, isotropic, coisotropic, and symplectic.

If we consider the space $\mathcal{L}(n)$ of all Lagrangian subspaces, it has a homogeneous structure:
$$
\mathcal{L}(n) \;\; = \;\; U(n)/O(n)
$$

where if we think of the embedding $U(n)\hookrightarrow GL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ as
$$
X+iY \;\; \to \;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
X & - Y \\ Y & X \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

then each Lagrangian subspace can be thought of as the span of the first $n$ columns of the above matrix, and these spans are invariant under right multiplication of $O(n)\times O(n)$.

**My question is: do the other canonical subspaces hold homogeneous structures of this form?**

For instance if we consider the set $\mathcal{I}(k)$ of isotropic subspaces of dimension $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, then I believe we can similarly form a unitary matrix of the type above where we pick $n\times k$ matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that
$$
\left [ \begin{array}{c}
X\\Y\\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

forms a unitary frame for the subspace.  Assuming it's possible to complete these to $n\times n$ matrices $\widetilde{X}, \widetilde{Y}$ such that $\widetilde{X}^T\widetilde{Y} = \widetilde{Y}^T\widetilde{X}$ then we can form a unitary matrix:
$$
\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\widetilde{X} & - \widetilde{Y} \\
\widetilde{Y} & \widetilde{X} \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$ 
and that a subspace can be represented by such a matrix mod right multiplication of the group $O(k)\times O(2n-k)$.  Is it then possible to conclude that:
$$
\mathcal{I}(k) \;\; =\;\; \frac{U(n)}{O(k)\times O(2n-k)}?
$$

If this is true, then how do we go about constructing homogeneous structures for the set of coisotropic subspaces $\mathcal{C}(n+k)$, and the space of symplectic subspaces $\mathcal{S}(2k)$?

For reference, this question is based on a passage in McDuff & Salamon's *Intro to Symplectic Topology* where they prove the above claim for Lagrangian subspaces, but then pose an exercise where they ask the reader to prove "analogous statements" for the other types of subspaces.